# Class Inheritance, redefining __init__ on with taking a new argument

Tags: python, class, inheritance, pygame

I'm new to Python, I still have issues with the semantics of class inheritance.

The following is the relevant class from the module games.py module that I am importing:

```
class Text(Sprite): 
    """ 
    Alphanumeric values displayed on the screen.
    """      
    def __init__(self, value, size, color, angle=0, 
                 x=0, y=0,
                 top=None, bottom=None, left=None, right=None,
                 dx=0, dy=0,
                 interval=1, is_collideable=True):
        self._size = size 
        self._color = color 
        self._value = value
        self._font = pygame.font.Font(None, self._size)
        Sprite.__init__(self, self._create_surface(), angle,
                        x, y,
                        top, bottom, left, right,
                        dx, dy,
                        interval, is_collideable)
```

and the following is from where I'm trying to call it in my own program:

```
self.scorebox = games.Text (value = self.scorevar,
                            pygame.font.Font(ardarlingopentype, 50),
                            color = color.white,
                            x = 550,
                            y = 50)
```

As you can see the syntax is wrong, but how do I go about fixing this such that I can inherit the class Text from my own program and make FONT an accessible argument that I can change?

Thanks.

Comment: I notice your second argument is not a named argument.  Unnamed arguments cannot follow named arguments.

Comment: Instead of using `Sprite.__init__(self, ...)`, use `super(Text, self).__init__(...)`.

Comment: At first, I'd not recommend to use `super()` it does not seem to be the problem of the OP, it can be [pretty complicated](http://fuhm.net/super-harmful/), there is no diamod inheritance in the problem and the [`Sprite` class does not use `super()` itself](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Python/Game-2D-3D/Pygame/pygame-1.9.1release/lib/sprite.py.htm). I may not get something, however. Why should he use `super()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure(note that you can't used not named arguments after named and/or mix them - you have used not named argument after 'value') but seems that you need to modify code the following way:

```
class Text(Sprite): 
    """ 
    Alphanumeric values displayed on the screen.
    """      
    def __init__(self, value, size, color, angle=0, 
                 x=0, y=0,
                 top=None, bottom=None, left=None, right=None, font=None,
                 dx=0, dy=0,
                 interval=1, is_collideable=True):
        self._size = size 
        self._color = color 
        self._value = value
        if font:
            self.font_ = font
        else:
            self._font = pygame.font.Font(None, self._size)
        Sprite.__init__(self, self._create_surface(), angle,
                        x, y,
                        top, bottom, left, right,
                        dx, dy,
                        interval, is_collideable)
```

And then:

```
import pygame
import games

self.scorebox = games.Text (value = self.scorevar,
                            size = 50,
                            color = color.white,
                            x = 550,
                            y = 50)
```

OR:

```
import pygame
import games

self.scorebox = games.Text (value = self.scorevar,
                            size = 50, 
                            font = pygame.font.Font(ardarlingopentype, 50),
                            color = color.white,
                            x = 550,
                            y = 50)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is, that you you are ordering the arguments incorrectly: there are positional and keyword arguments. All keywords arguments must **succeed** the positional arguments.

This would work:

```
self.scorebox = games.Text (
                        pygame.font.Font(ardarlingopentype, 50),
                        value = self.scorevar,
                        color = color.white,
                        x = 550,
                        y = 50
)
```

Comment: @Louis93: Can you define "didn't work" ?  Syntactically, this should be correct.

Comment: Sorry! I received a response from the developers of the Livewires package. Look at the answer right below! I'm sorry should've posted earlier. thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

So guys I wrote to the developers of the Livewires package; and I was fortunate enough to receive a reply from one of them.

> First, make a backup copy of games.py and put it somewhere safe.  That
>   way if you do make a mistake, you can always recover the original
>   code.
>
> Now our games.py is written on top of the PyGame library, which does
>   provide a way of setting the font.  As you might have guessed, it's to
>   do with that line reading:

```
> self._font = pygame.font.Font(None, self._size)
```

> The documentation is available online at
>   http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font but I'll
>   just quickly summarise here.  pygame.font.Font() creates a new PyGame
>   font object, which PyGame uses to tell it how to draw text.  The
>   "None" parameter tells it to use the default font, but you can replace
>   that with the full name of a font file instead.  The easiest way to do
>   that is to modify the Text classes initialiser to pass it as an
>   optional parameter.

```
class Text(Sprite):

                  def __init__(self, value, size, color, angle=0,
>                               x=0, y=0,
>                               top=None, bottom=None, left=None, right=None,
>                               dx=0, dy=0,
>                               interval=1, is_collideable=True,
>                               fontfile=None):
>        self._size = size
>        self._color = color
>        self._value = value
>        self._font = pygame.font.Font(fontfile, self._size)
>        Sprite.__init__(self, self._create_surface(), angle,
>                        x, y,
>                        top, bottom, left, right,
>                        dx, dy,
>                        interval, is_collideable)
```

> You would then create your Text object by calling 'Text(blah blah
>   blah, fontfile="/some/font/file/name.ttf")' or whatever the filename
>   is.  Any other Text objects that don't specify a "fontfile" will
>   automatically use "None" instead, which will give them the default
>   font exactly as before.
>
> So what's the fully-qualified pathname of the font file for
>   "TimesNewRoman"?  I have no idea what it would be on your computer. 
>   Fortunately PyGame provides a way of not having to know:
>   pygame.font.match_font().  You can use that in your own program
>   (rather than modifying games.py any more), but you will have to either
>   "import pygame.font" for yourself or call it
>   "games.pygame.font.match_font()" -- either should work equally well.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? "First, make a backup copy of games.py and put it somewhere safe. That way if you do make a mistake, you can always recover the original code." You should rather use something like Git or Mercurial.